# 2 vpn Combined..Questions

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

Hello so i have some theoritical questions about combining 2 vpns using a virtual machine.I whould test it my self but don't have the budget right now so my questions are:

1)If i use one vpn provider in the Host pc and then one other vpn provider for the virtual machine whould it stack?In this case the host pc will have vpn1 ip and the vm vpn2 ip?If yes the vm should be on Nat or bridged adapter?

2)Assuming i want to forward some ports on vm,but only vpn2 allow portforward.If i use the previous setup (2 vpns)will the ports in vm be open?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for VirtualBox but I assume the following answers are also valid for other virtualisation applications.

1. You already mentioned the two options you have: NAT or Network Bridge.

   1. With NAT, the two VPN connections stack. The Guest (VM) won't receive an IP by your LAN DHCP server but use the Host as a gateway. Therefore the Guest even receives the VPN's external IP address if it's not connected to any VPN. In case Host and Guest are connected to tweo different VPN servers, every traffic from the Guest is first tunneled through VPN1 and then through VPN2.
   2. With a network bridge as adapter, the Guest receives an internal IP address from the LAN's DHCP server just like the host. Even if the Host is connected to the VPN, the Guest still uses the normal WAN IP address. So 2 VPNs will not stack using this mode.
2. From my first answer you should be able to derive the second answer: Using NAT, the port forwarding won't work because every traffic to/from Guest is using VPN1 (from Host) which is not supporting port forwarding. But using Bridge, it should be possible because VPN1 isn't used but only the port-forwarding-supporting VPN2.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested answer 2 practically due to the lack of port-forwarding VPN servers to test it.*